# Using yocto recipes, how to build ROS2 application depending on workspace?

Tags: ros2, rosdep, colcon

I'm working on packaging a ROS2 application for yocto.
I have ROS2 installed in my image and can run the demos.

Now, I'm stuck with the dependencies for the application. They are configured in a file `remote/workspace.repo` and, when compiling natively, we would run

```bash
vcs import --input "remote/workspace.repos" "remote"
# Update rosdep and install packages
rosdep update
rosdep install -y --from-paths "local" "remote" --ignore-src
```

And then build the application with `colcon build`.

What's the proper way, via a yocto recipe, to build an application like that?

Thanks
Dom